# Conditionally merge two dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in my data frame for gender derived from first name and middle name. I want to create a third column for overall gender. As such, where there is male or female in either column, it should override the unknown in the other column. I've written the following function but end up with the following error:

```
# Assign gender for names so that number of female names can be counted.
d = gender.Detector()
trnY['Gender_first'] = trnY['first'].map(lambda x: d.get_gender(x))
trnY['Gender_mid'] = trnY['middle'].map(lambda x: d.get_gender(x))

# merge the two gender columns:
def gender(x):
    if ['Gender_first'] == male or ['Gender_mid'] == male:
        return male
    elif ['Gender_first'] == female or ['Gender_mid'] == female:
        return female
    else:
        return unknown

trnY['Gender'] =  trnY.apply(gender)
 
trnY

Error: 
--> 50 trnY['Gender'] =  trnY.apply(gender)
ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, the length must be 21: given 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `apply()` on rows you should pass it the parameter `axis=1`. In your case.

```
def gender(x):
    if x['Gender_first'] == male or x['Gender_mid'] == male:
        return male
    elif x['Gender_first'] == female or x['Gender_mid'] == female:
        return female
    else:
        return unknown

trnY['Gender'] = trnY.apply(gender, axis=1)
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me! I've tried it out and I'm receiving the following error: 
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().